# Button doesn't go to new page?

Tags: android, eclipse

I created a button and I want it to go to another page when clicked on. I think I did everything right but when I ran the project in the emulator the button didn't do anything and it gives me the error that the project has stopped working and the app stops working on the emulator. And ideas?

Here is the xml for the button

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:hint="@string/Play_Button" />
```

Here is the java for the button

```
package com.dakota.amnesiadino;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button play_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    play_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            startActivity(new Intent("com.dakota.amnesiadino.play_button"));

        }
    });
}

}
```

and here is the manifest for the button

```
                <activity
        android:name="com.dakota.amnesiadino.levels_home"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.play_button" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, be more specific when you say "did not go to the next page"
This page is a screen?? Is an activity defined by an xml file? Is a web url?? 
It is not very clearly typed your question.

As I understand, 
probably, you should write something like this inside the OnClick body..

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),levels_home.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

This solution could work if you have an xml file and a corresponding .java file for the new  activity.

Answer (score 0):

for the best way of doing it is like this :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),levels_home.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

and setting the manifest:

```
<activity
    android:name="com.dakota.amnesiadino.levels_home"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
```

in your manifest the issue with LAUNCHER probably copy and paste error it should be DEFAULT:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.play_button" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```